# Using the 'exoplanet' module to fit a radial velocity curve for a binary star system

Tags: exoplanet, python, radial-velocity

As part of a project, I am trying to fit a radial velocity curve using the [tutorial for the binary star system (EBLM J0608-59)](https://docs.exoplanet.codes/en/stable/tutorials/rv/) My code is quite similar to the tutorial, but as it is only one body orbiting the main star, I have not used the shape arguments in the `Model` section. I have the time measurements and corresponding radial velocities:

```
bjd_arr = [2458549.66666822, 2458488.75868917, 2458721.8842678, 2458216.52944096, 2458777.86519712, 2458730.87419918, 2458503.73189952, 2458740.81585069, 2458717.86935648, 2458566.60445361, 2458708.90058602, 2458698.93553665, 2458556.64600867, 2458537.693232, 2458553.66510611, 2458436.82194322, 2458726.88080012, 2458516.71230084]
RVarr = [40.4432860896165, 23.5780860488492, 19.1436760180712, 50.786661126373, 7.57399767050893, 33.7977531116774, 26.2274095792521, 46.7356539726255, 14.8623891652762, 50.1464417200217, 30.9220153319253, 50.7551660448898, 20.5739440645183, 50.6114884906977, 49.0286951865467, 48.9542544284423, 49.1472667204292, 14.7099410033466] 
RVerr_arr = [0.00746727240668619, 0.0071426759147196405, 0.007709525952827119, 0.00749855434080898, 0.00811465321639329, 0.00802464048008298, 0.00773122855735923, 0.00789124901574783, 0.007773933655270579, 0.00753401931897191, 0.00822360876229237, 0.00741660549431721, 0.0079125927446526, 0.007308327482575159, 0.00868241919549683, 0.00794049877685647, 0.00781335663783952, 0.0076679825576695] 
periods = 14.608810

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pymc3 as pm
import exoplanet as xo
import theano.tensor as tt

x = np.array(bjd_arr)
y = np.array(RVarr)
yerr = np.array(RVerr_arr)


period_errs = 0.011184
t0s = (min(bjd_arr)+max(bjd_arr))/2 # transit time (rough estimate)
t0_errs = 0.011184
Ks = xo.estimate_semi_amplitude(periods, x, y, yerr, t0s=t0s)
print(Ks, "km/s")
print(type(Ks))

print(float(Ks))
x_ref = 0.5 * (x.min() + x.max())
t = np.linspace(x.min() - 5, x.max() + 5, 1000)

'''Making RV model'''
with pm.Model() as model:

    # Gaussian priors based on transit data (from Petigura et al.)
    t0 = pm.Normal("t0", mu=(t0s), sd=(t0_errs))
    P = pm.Bound(pm.Normal, lower=0)(
        "P",
        mu=(periods),
        sd=(period_errs),
        testval=(periods),
    )

    # Wide log-normal prior for semi-amplitude
    logK = pm.Bound(pm.Normal, lower=0)(
        "logK", mu=float(np.log(Ks)), sd=10.0, testval=float(np.log(Ks))
    )

    # Eccentricity & argument of periasteron
    ecc = xo.distributions.UnitUniform(
        "ecc", testval=0.1
    )
    omega = xo.distributions.Angle("omega")

    # Jitter & a quadratic RV trend
    logs = pm.Normal("logs", mu=np.log(np.median(yerr)), sd=5.0)
    trend = pm.Normal("trend", mu=0, sd=10.0 ** -np.arange(2)[::-1], shape=2)

    # Then we define the orbit
    orbit = xo.orbits.KeplerianOrbit(period=P, t0=t0, ecc=ecc, omega=omega)

    # And a function for computing the full RV model
    def get_rv_model(t, name=""):
        # First the RVs induced by the planets
        vrad = orbit.get_radial_velocity(t, K=tt.exp(logK))
        pm.Deterministic("vrad" + name, vrad)

        # Define the background model
        A = np.vander(t - x_ref, 2)
        bkg = pm.Deterministic("bkg" + name, tt.dot(A, trend))

        # Sum over planets and add the background to get the full model
        return pm.Deterministic("rv_model" + name, tt.sum(vrad, axis=-1) + bkg)

    # Define the RVs at the observed times
    rv_model = get_rv_model(x)

    # Also define the model on a fine grid as computed above (for plotting)
    rv_model_pred = get_rv_model(t, name="_pred")

    # Finally add in the observation model. This next line adds a new contribution
    # to the log probability of the PyMC3 model
    err = tt.sqrt(yerr ** 2 + tt.exp(2 * logs))
    pm.Normal("obs", mu=rv_model, sd=err, observed=y)

'''Initial model'''

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr=yerr, fmt=".k")

with model:
    plt.plot(t, xo.eval_in_model(model.vrad_pred), "--k", alpha=0.5,label='star')
    plt.plot(t, xo.eval_in_model(model.bkg_pred), ":k", alpha=0.5,label='bkg')
    plt.plot(t, xo.eval_in_model(model.rv_model_pred), label="model")

plt.legend(fontsize=10)
plt.xlim(t.min(), t.max())

plt.xlabel("time [days]")
plt.ylabel("radial velocity [km/s]")
_ = plt.title("initial model")
```

This codes produces the following graph:
[image: Graph here]

I thought this would work but I am getting the wrong model curve, where the model curve is just a straight line and was wondering if I was missing something obvious? I suspect there is something wrong in maybe the `def get_rv_model` function but I am not sure (I'm still a bit inexperienced with coding), so any guidance would be appreciated. This code works fine when I use it for K2-24 like they do in the example.

Comment: what does the line periods=hpp do? The obvious possible problem is that you are not starting off with a sensible guess for the period.

Comment: @ProfRob hpp = 14.608810 (I m gonna remove that line to prevent confusion). The period was found through a periodogram and is close to the true value

Comment: You need to put numbers on your plot so we can see what's going on, but it looks off-topic to me - i.e. a coding problem (perhaps) and not a question about astronomy.

Comment: Are you able to use pymc3 for other problems? In other words, are you asking for help using pymc3 or do you have a question that relates to Astronomy?